# Parse log file continuously and send out a URL request to a predetermined IP address

Tags: python, rsyslog, python3

We have a radius server which forwards the accounting messages to a Syslog server hosted on Linux server. we want to gather specific values from that log file and use those values as parameters in a URL to be sent out to web-server as a request.

The code should 
1. Continuously parse a log file (`radiusmsg.log`) in Linux server: The code will do the `tail -f` every 2 sec, checks for a new line, finds a specific keyword with in the log file.

2. Search for a particular keyword called `Acct-Status-Type=Start`.
3. If above keyword is present in the log entry, then the script has to find values within that log i.e. the value of `User-Name` and `Framed-IP-Address`.

   ```
   User-Name="Harvey.specter" 
   Framed-IP-Address="10.0.0.16"
   ```
4. the script should finally should **send out a URL request as an output to a pre-determined IP address, e.g. 1.1.1.1.**

   ```
   https://1.1.1.1:8999/wbc/APICrl?requexml=<request><login><username><Harvey.specter><ipaddress> <10.0.0.16></ipaddress></username></login>
   ```

Example of log entry:

```
CISE_RADIUS_Accounting 000011 1 0 2016-05-09 12:53:52.823 +03:00 0000012451 3000 NOTICE Radius-Accounting: RADIUS Accounting start request, ConfigVersionId=104, Device IP Address=10.0.0.12, RequestLatency=12, NetworkDeviceName=DefaultNetworkDevice, User-Name=Harvey.specter, NAS-IP-Address=10.0.0.1, Framed-IP-Address=10.0.0.16, Session-Timeout=90, Calling-Station-ID=, Acct-Status-Type=Start, Acct-Session-Id=6, cisco-av-pair=audit-session-id=5
```

Comment: That looks like you might be interested in looking at fail2ban. It is mostly geared towards finding IPs in logfiles and doing something if they occur too often, but if you set that to "once in one second is too much", that might fit into your requirements?

Comment: Why would you do a `tail -f` every 2 seconds?  That's just wrong and doesn't make sense.